# Results from a for cycle into an array?

Tags: c#

I am new in C# so my question could be very stupid for you. Anyway - I am trying to get all results that a for cycle produses into a single array. Is this possible and if it is - how?

example:

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++){ 
     int[] array = 5 << i
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the array before the loop with the size required:

```
int[] result = new int[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) {
  result[i] = 5 << i;
}
```

If you don't know the size beforehand, you can use a list instead:

```
List<int> result = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) {
  result.Add(5 << i);
}
```

Comment: Your array is 1 too big, it should be `new int[5]`. You would use `new int[6]` if you had `i <= 5` in the loop.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Yes, of course, don't know how I was thinking... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] YourArray = new int[5];
for(i=0; i<5; i++)
{
   YourArray[i] = somevalue;
}
```

read [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for more examples

Comment: please elaborate that the array declaration should be done outside the loop - it would help the OP I guess

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you wanted numbers 0 to 4 in the array, or the result of 5 bit-shifted in the array:

```
int[] values = new int[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  values[i] = i;
}
```

or

```
int[] values = new int[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  values[i] = 5 << i;
}
```